# tradingview selections disappear on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, tradingview-api

Tradingview selections disappear when the page is refreshed, when the indicator is selected, I want it to come back when the page is refreshed. How can I do that ?

I tried to add enabled_features it didn't work.
thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to persist user interactions with the chart and you don't want to use backend apis, you should use browser's local storage.